# Using application data structures other than xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm designing a survey tool.  The survey will be very static and because of that, I can avoid building some kind of table-driven survey designer to accommodate the 167 questions on the survey (all 1-5 rating questions in a radio box or checkbox layout).

I was thinking of building the survey questions in a large XML file, but my non-technical co-worker that will be making frequent edits to the survey will likely do things that will break the integrity/validity of the raw xml file (think punctuation and special characters).

The XML file might look something like:

```
    <questions>
    <question>
        <type>checkbox</type>
        <text>Which beers do you like most</text>
        <choices>Bud,Miller,Piels</choices>
        <Required>true</Required>
    </question>
    <question>
        <type>radio</type>
        <text>Which beer is your favorite</text>
        <choices>Bud,Miller,Piels</choices>
        <Required>true</Required>
    </question>
</questions>
```

Please use your imagination that this structure will be a bit more complex and that there will be 165 more questions.

Complicating matters, I need these questions in some form of object-oriented layout so that I can take the results and align them to other stuff.  I had considered hard-coding a very lengthy survey form with 167 questions, but I need the data in blocks so that I can parse out question 37 and align it to something else in some other feature, that is related to question 37.

Here's what I'd like to do in a .Net app:

1. Define a enumerable class for this.
2. Do something where I can manually fill an enumerable collection of this class with all of the data I need. Using the p-code that would be familiar in my .asp world  . . .

   ```
   questions q = new questions()

   q.type = "checkbox";
   q.text = "which beers do you enjoy"'
   q.choices = "Bud,Miller,Peils";
   q.required = true;
   q.add

   q.type = "radio";
   q.text = "what is your favorite beer";
   q.choices = "Bud,Miller,Peils";
   q.required = true;
   q.add
   ```

My hope is that this .cs file (though foreign looking to the lay person) would be much easier for my co-worker to maintain, without me having to worry about syntax errors.

So, I guess what I'm looking for some feedback on:

1. Is this just a dumb idea.  Should I do this in XML and I'll just consume the XML file and be done with it.
2. WWYD - What would you do? Is there an easier way to do this?

   - I don't care about performance as a relatively small number of users are using this.
   - I don't care about maintainability, because we will write this feature properly in the summer.
   - I just need to create a data structure that is not in a DB and that can be maintained by a non-technical person with a text-editor (for now).

If anyone made it this far, I appreciate it.

Comment: Just spend 5 minutes explain how the XML works and you are good to go. Also, maybe define a XSD and validate the XML before you use it. In my opinion, the XML way is the easiest solution. Changing the code files, is a bad idea. Because for each edit or new survey, you need to compile; while with an "external datasource" (XML) you can just load the survey.

Comment: -- or create a visual designer. -- but yes, XML is the way to go. If you provide XSD your coworker can use Visual Studio (or any other XML-capable editor such as Altova) which provides Intellisense (auto-complete) and syntax validation features.

Comment: I didn't think of XSD.  That's a great idea.

Comment: If you want up-most maintainability you'll need to provide a GUI for the consumer in a (possibly) master-detail way. No way that can give you syntax errors and it can be done in a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As permanent store XML is good.
But that does not mean the user needs to edit the XML directly.
I would build the ability to edit, add, and delete the questions in the app.
Yes a bit a trouble but if they hack the XML then that is also a lot of trouble.

How do you plan to save survey results?
How do you plan to collect the survey results?
There is more to this project than you are realizing.
Do you need to combine results from more than one device?
If more than one device then you need to separate the questions from the results so you can update the questions on more than one device.

There are tools to read and write XML to disk.
[Reading XML with the XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d83k261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
I don't agree with doug that you need to embed a database.
For a small number of questions I would use XML.
I would read all the XML into an object collection (A List).
You don't need a class the implements IEnumerable.
You put you objects in a a collections that implements IEnumerable.

I would go WPF over WinForms.
A ListBox with a DataTemplate.
On the DataTemplate you can have a dynamic selector in code behind but that is a real hassel.
Consider a single template that you manipulate in code behind.
So they are not RadioButtons but you uncheck the others in code behind.
For filtering I would go LINQ in public properties but there is also CollectionViewSource.

Used XML for an app that was used to collect field measurements.
A lot like this in measuring devices could change and need to collect the measurements.

If you are set on user editing the questions directly then XML with XSD is the best I can think of.

Comment: I disagree with you: "WPF over WinForms". WPF has a steeper learning curve than WinForms.

Comment: @Measuring He is new to .NET and comes from an ASP background.  Fine is not better.

Comment: ASP and WPF are not alike. Because he is new to .NET I wouldn't suggest a more complex framework.

Comment: @Measuring Maybe it is more complex to you but it was not more complex to me and I came from an ASP backgound.  Really you don't see similarity of HTML and XAML?

Comment: I was not talking about my experience with WPF. I am disagreeing with you but that's just an opinion. Similarities with HTML and XAML are by syntax but what you type in each one does differ a lot.

Comment: @Measuring But they are both declarative page layout.  If you are going to invest time in learning .NET then I feel like your time is much better spent on WPF as I feel it is much more powerful.  Now if I had told him MVVM for a small app then that would be another thing.  Cheers

Comment: @measuring `WPF has a steeper learning curve` - Wrong. WPF is way better and **EASIER** than the procedural too-much-code-for-anything winforms approach, which by the way doesn't support anything. WPF allows a simple UI to be created in **NO TIME** and then **DataBound** to **ANY** DataSource in a **Declarative** manner, as opposed to having to deal with `cmbMyCombo_SelectionChanged` type of stuff. Try again bringing some relevant argument as to why WPF would be any harder than winforms for a non-winforms developer.

Comment: @HighCore You yourself are not providing any arguments besides "It's better and faster than" and "Databinding". WinForms also has DataBinding where you can bind properties to Controls. It's not as extensive as WPF though. I found WPF harder to pick-up than WinForms, that is why I disagreed. Also, "Try again bringing some relevant..", again, I'm not trying to dump WPF here.

Comment: @Measuring alright, I can give you some technical arguments as to why WPF is easier than winforms: 1 - it has *real* DataBinding, as opposed to the ridiculous joke that winforms provides. 2 - it has built-in support for Master/Detail scenarios. 3 - it has a comprehensive `Styling` mechanism which allows to set visual styles to the UI in an per-Control/per-Window/application-wide manner, something that is completely absent in winforms. 4 - it does not force you to horrible "owner draw" hacks to do any custom drawing. 5 - it does not force you to lose your time trying to fix the horrible flicker

Comment: @Measuring 6 - it allows you to "do more with less", mainly by introducing the `ItemsControl` approach where you can deal with whatever collections of data in a clean, beautiful way, and achieve any level of customization in the UI, as opposed to a bunch of horrible `for` loops from 500 years ago. 7 - In general, achieving any Items-Based or custom UI in WPF takes 10% the code than the same thing in winforms, and the resulting UI is generally better.

Comment: @HighCore I must say, it is a good read for the biggest pros on WPF over WinForms. I'm not gonna go and counter it with WinForms features because I do not know any that are clear winner. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments.  I realize there's more to this than just the survey design.  I'm just trying to find a way to ease the burden of building a survey/form designer.  I'm just persisting the form design in an xml file, as opposed to a database.

Comment: @measuring just in case you'd like to have a look, a just created [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21898676/643085) in WPF in 10 minutes that would have taken 500 engineers from NASA working around the clock for 10 years to achieve a similar thing in winforms.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone uses Excel...so consider using a CSV format which can be read by you as well as Excel which your counterpart will be using. One must specify to the user that the columns can't be changed, which is not a drawback per-se, but the user exports the *dynamic* changes to CSV which the program reads and can verify.

Plus the user does not have to be trained to use Excel so it is a win/win situation per your requirements not to use XMl.

Comment: -1 This doesn't cater for the OP's concerns about data format and correctness. An Excel sheet does not guarantee any type of data correctness, and it's also not a optimal way to represent a hierarchical structure.

Comment: @HighCore if the rule is one can't use XML...what other choices are there? Structured data. Good luck on that one. If a user has to use a tool, Excel is better than some developer tool and the user can *understand* how to use it without training. IMHO

Comment: an Excel sheet that is **complex enough** so that it can properly model and represent the **hierarchical** data structure needed by the OP will also require training the user. I would venture that even an editable WPF TreeView is better than an Excel sheet for this purpose.

Comment: and the OP did not say that `not` using XML was a requirement. Read the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simple human readable structured format, then you could be interrested by [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML).

> YAML is a human-readable data serialization format that takes concepts
>   from programming languages such as C, Perl, and Python, and ideas from
>   XML and the data format of electronic mail.

Your question file would look like this:

```
questions:
   - id:       1
     type:     checkbox
     text:     Which beers do you like most
     choices:  Bud,Miller,Piels
     Required: true

   - id:       2
     type:     radio
     text:     Which beer is your favorite
     choices:  Bud,Miller,Piels
     Required: true
```

Some YAML libraries exists in .NET (from the article):

https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet

http://yaml.codeplex.com/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28720/YAML-Parser-in-C

http://yaml-net-parser.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of xml editing tools out there that will actually make it easier to edit than editing a text file directly. I use XML Marker and it's pretty easy to use. http://symbolclick.com/

It will be quicker to train them to edit using the tool than it will be to build one.

Answer (score 0):

Two answers here;

a: Write it to allow a proper admin interface, using a database to allow admin users to add/edit questions, response options and include appropriate security, auditing etc. You mention that this may not be feasible in the short term or that a 'proper' feature will be added soon, in which case, scrap this!

b: People say they have frequent edits/changes to make, but is this not a requirement which is co-related to a complete feature? Could you not in the short term, accept manual requests for change via email or something else documented, and make them yourself? Do you think the time taking to add a question/response or change some wording would be less than needing to parse XML manually to find a syntax error from someone who isn't familiar?

You'll need to weigh up frequency of change with impact to yourself of making a change vs likelihood of user error, vs estimated time needed to identify and resolve a syntax error (plus the possible bad-will of having a change break things).
Despite what some people think, users don't like making mistakes! putting them in a position where they have admin level powers over a system they don't have a full technical grasp of, could reduce confidence and future buy-in to the feature you're due to develop.

TLDR; In my opinion, unless it's a major hassle, do the changes yourself in the short term, perhaps with a maximum amount of time you'll make them (I make one change set a week, on a Friday for example). Keep the system working perfectly, and involve the users without putting them in an uncomfortable position being an non voluntary early adopter for a feature which isn't finished.

Answer (score 0):

I used my complete mastery over winforms to create a little mock GUI application that enables users to quickly create one dimensional non conditional lists of questions with different question types.

Once you decided on an xml scheme you can easily import and export xml files.

Are you interested in further development of the magical survey creator? If so tell me and I will send you a practically finished prototype tomorrow morning. (You should provide me with an xml scheme though, otherwise I will do it in CSV)
I enjoy the exercise.
Picture related. Don't be put off by the colors, that's how I like it during development, to see the pixel exact boundaries of controls.

Unless your coworkers have some experience with programming or xml editing they will hate you if you instruct them to edit any sort of "code".
Our secretaries put their hand in front of their faces and start chanting "no, no, no..." when I tell them how to operate VBA macros.

[image]

Comment: We are charging ahead quickly and it's looking more and more like we will fight with XML for now (with all of it's raw editing challenges) and then we'll use MVC/Razor to render the form and save the results.