# Need a very customized large Winforms grid

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I am about to develop a Windows PC application (it can be WinForms or WPF) and my main concern is a UI problem I will have to address.

Basically, I need to have a grid of about 50x50 that I need to get input from the user for.  That's 2500 fields.  Realistically most will be left blank, about 10% will be filled out by a user.  Each field can be blank or have a number from 1 to 4.  I want easy input - a drop down box perhaps (since it doesn't make sense to tab through all 2500 fields when with the keyboard, I want the user to fill out the values with the mouse).

I was thinking the drop down boxes or maybe even labels that change value when you click them, but the problem is (from the tests I've done) adding 2500 of ANY type of control will make the interface horribly slow.  I tried using a tablelayoutpanel in a WinForms app with the suspend/resumeupdate functions, and also doublebuffering and that helps a bit, but it's still terribly slow.  I am reluctant to go the DataGridView route because I need VERY custom headers and I need the UI to auto update some percentages as the user changes values in the fields.  But I will not be opposed if that's my only option.

I heard WPF may be better since you can have many controls and each one doesn't take its own windows handle, and there's virtualization (not sure how hard that is to implement).

I'm open to suggestions.  I know someone will suggest to break up the grid, which I may end up doing.  Either way, I'd like to know the most efficient method for a large grid with many controls in a Windows app as if I were going to develop this without breaking up the grid.

I'm using VS 2013, developing in C#, .NET 4.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As demonstrated by @Kerry's answer, the winforms answer to almost everything is *"you can't do that in winforms, therefore you need to create a much poorer substitute UI design that fits into winforms limitations."* - that is not what I would expect from any decent UI framework.

This is what I achieved in **WPF** in **10 minutes** with some **20 lines of C# code** and **50 lines of XAML**:

[image]

- The response time when interacting with this WPF UI is **Immediate** on my machine (an I5 CPU and a regular video card). Even with **no virtualization** (since I'm using an `UniformGrid` which does not virtualize), this is way better than anything you can ever hope to achieve in winforms.
- I introduced a `ComboBox` with numbers 1-4 as you requested.
- **Fully customizable** (without resorting to any "owner draw" hacks). I even added these Row and Column numbers which of course are all part of the scrollable area.
- **Touch-Ready** - this kind of big-scrolling UI is really better suited for a touch device. Something that the winforms paradigm does not even take into account. Otherwise, you could also implement Excel-like keyboard navigation in the grid with the arrow keys to create a better non-touch user experience.
- With a **small effort** you could also make the row and column headers **fixed** while retaining their consistency with the scroll offset of the entire grid.
- This is actually a `ListBox`, which means it has the concept of `SelectedItem` and it also by default exhibits the ListBox-like visual style (you can see the light-blue background and outline on the selected item).
- The logic is **decoupled** from the UI by creating a proper **ViewModel** with a collection of Items and then using [**ItemsControls**](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) to let WPF do it's job of creating the UI. There's not a single line of C# code in this example that manipulates any UI element. It's all done via beautiful [**DataBinding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx).

Full source:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MarkerTemplate">
            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Margin="1" Background="Gainsboro">
                <Grid Width="50" Height="30">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid Width="50" Height="30">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" SelectedItem="{Binding Value}" 
                                  IsDropDownOpen="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                                  Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                            <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
                            <sys:Int32>3</sys:Int32>
                            <sys:Int32>4</sys:Int32>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ComboBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <ListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ColumnMarkers}"
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MarkerTemplate}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>

                            <ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding RowMarkers}"
                                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MarkerTemplate}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>

                            <UniformGrid Rows="50" Columns="50" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListBox.Template>
        </ListBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<string> RowMarkers { get; set; }

    public List<string> ColumnMarkers { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        RowMarkers = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
        ColumnMarkers = new[] { " " }.Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(x => x.ToString())).ToList();

        var list = new List<Item>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
            {
                list.Add(new Item());
            }
        }

        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(list);
    }
}
```

Data Item:

```
public class Item
{
    public int? Value { get; set; }
}
```

- You will probably want to add `Row` and `Column` properties to the `Item` class so that you can keep track of what rows/columns actually contain values. Then You could use LINQ like so:

  ```
  var values = Items.Where(x => Value != null);
  ```

  and obtain a list of `Item`s and get `item.Row` and `Item.Column` for each of them.
- **Forget winforms. It's completely useless.** - at this point, winforms is completely obsolete. Whatever you can achieve with winforms, you can achieve the same thing in WPF with 10% the amount of code and probably with much better results. winforms is not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications. It is an ancient technology that is not suited to cater for today's UI needs. That's why Microsoft created WPF to *replace* it.
- **WPF Rocks**. Just copy and paste my code in a `File -> New Project -> WPF Application` and see the results for yourself.
- Let me know if you need further help.

> **Important Note:** the WPF default control templates are much lighter weight in Windows 8 than their Windows 7 counterparts (following the
>   Windows 8 philosophy of removing the heavy Aero stuff and practically
>   all transparencies to have a smaller UI footprint).
>
> This means that testing my code on Windows 7 might not yield the
>   expected results in terms of performance. If that happens to be the
>   case, Don't worry. It is fixable. A small amount of additional XAML
>   would have to be introduced (some `Style`s and `ControlTemplate`s) to
>   replace the Windows 7 defaults by something "faster".

Comment: It's unfortunate that you cannot provide such a wonderful answer without trashing the alternative.  If WPF is so great, wouldn't it speak for itself?

Comment: @DonBoitnott doesn't the example speak for itself anyways? and I'm not "trashing" anything. I'm presenting technical reasons as to why winforms is completely useless.

Comment: WOW!  Great Answer, very thorough! Thanks so much.  I agree WPF seems to be performing so much faster and be much more flexible.  I hadn't really considered using a listbox instead of a datagrid so that's helpful as well.  Thanks again.

Comment: As said yesterday I will always face this problem by relying on DataGridView (if you have a so comprehensive control delivering precisely this functionality, why creating everything from scratch? -> and I am saying that despite of liking doing things from scratch a lot); I am not even sure why you haven't used the WPF equivalent of DataGrid (but well... you are the expert there). I have posted a (logically, quickly-built) version here: http://pastebin.com/GczzPPcj ...

Comment: ... to use this code, you just need to open a new Winforms project, double click on the form and replace all what is inside Namespace whatever with this code. This is the equivalent to all your C# + your XAML code. The looks is different (haven't cared too much about it), but also the behaviour (quicker response?). We can discuss about all this in yesterday's chat room (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93081/discussion-between-highcore-and-varocarbas).

Answer (score 4):

Although you've already got your answer and it's an old post, I will give you a solution using the *useless alternative*, just for sport and to show to some people that it's not as useless as they think. Of course it is faster to do some things in WPF (**IF** you know it very well) and maybe shorter most of the times, but if you're a real programmer, there is no such thing as 'useless framework'.

This is just a raw example (you won't use it anyway) so don't be the fussy kind. It could use some image for cells for better look etc, but that's not important. Anyway, **it's a complete Control (no designer code required), so if you paste the code in your solution somewhere, you will be able to place it on your form from the ToolBox** and you'll immediately see how it looks. Run it to test the behavior. Index it with [x,y] to get or set values programatically.

```
public class ValuesPanel : Panel
{
    public int this[int x, int y] { get { return cells[x, y]; } set { cells[x, y] = value; } }
    private int[,] cells = new int[50, 50];
    const int cell_width = 15, cell_height = 15;
    private int x, y, scroll_x, scroll_y;

    public ValuesPanel()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(50 * cell_width, 50 * cell_height);
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DeepSkyBlue, x * cell_width - scroll_x, y * cell_height - scroll_y, cell_width, cell_height);
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                int xx = i * cell_width - scroll_x, yy = j * cell_height - scroll_y;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(cells[i, j].ToString(), Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), new PointF(3 + xx, 1 + yy));
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gray, xx, yy, xx + cell_width - 2, yy);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gray, xx, yy + cell_height - 2, xx, yy);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, xx + 1, yy + cell_height - 1, xx + cell_width - 1, yy + cell_height - 1);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, xx + cell_width - 1, yy + 1, xx + cell_width - 1, yy + cell_height - 1);
            }
    }

    protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se)
    {
        Invalidate();
        base.OnScroll(se);
        scroll_x = HorizontalScroll.Value;
        scroll_y = VerticalScroll.Value;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        x = Math.Min(49, (e.Location.X + scroll_x) / cell_width);
        y = Math.Min(49, (e.Location.Y + scroll_y) / cell_height);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            cells[x, y] = (cells[x, y] % 4) + 1;
        else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            cells[x, y] = cells[x, y] < 2 ? 4 : cells[x, y] - 1;
    }
}
```

I really like WPF, but I can't stand someone calling WinForms "useless". Keep coding! ;)

Comment: LOL... nice hack... `e.Graphics.DrawLine(...)` and a bunch of horrible calculations... BTW your solution does not resize properly to the Window Size. That's called Resolution Independence, which you might not have heard of. Now compare these horrible hacks with my clean, scalable, customizable, even portable solution (in the sense that the actual logic does not depend on any UI classes and can be ported to other frameworks). you `can` do this in winforms, but WHY would you? the alternative is much better and does not require all this horrible code. It's **Useless**.

Comment: Not to mention I don't see a `ComboBox` anywhere here... +1 for the effort, though.

Comment: These kind of *calculations* are a piece of cake for me. Try doing some 3D geometry math, then you'll see some "horrible calculations"... ;)

I know it's not perfect, told you it's a raw example.

ComboBox is not needed in this case. Rob was asking for combo OR switchable label (by click). Anyway adding a popup on click wouldn't be so hard to implement too... You should have seen what I've already done on WinForms. You would be really suprised...

Comment: Also there is a *hack* to get the 1-4 keys to set a cell value (under the mouse) if you like:

    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnParentChanged(e);
        Form form = FindForm();
        if (form == null) return;
        form.KeyPreview = true;
        form.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(form_KeyPress);
    }

    void form_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar >= '1' && e.KeyChar <= '4')
        {
            cells[x, y] = (int)e.KeyChar - 48;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

Comment: LOL... a "popup"... what if there was a requirement that each cell have RICH editable content?...

Comment: Regarding the RazorFone app: maybe another time ;) I just spent too much time doing some really useless code :] Bye! ;)

Comment: I think that only WPF people think that Winforms is useless; perhaps because they (= you) don't know how to use it properly. I don't like WPF and do recognise that I don't know how to use it properly (and honestly don't care); but I focus my critics on "I don't like it", rather than it is... Anyway, if you want to support something you should use it properly; this problem should be faced via `DataGridView` (even `DataGrid` in WPF). You can take a look at my comment in HighCode answer above to understand how to face this situation properly in Winforms.

Comment: PS: also note that you might have plainly added all the ComboBoxes to a normal panel (= two nested loops including a few lines per ComboBox, like name, datasource and events). Why are you unnecessarily over-complicating things so much? And additionally to defend Winforms? Relying on the Paint event is almost never required! I seriously cannot understand you , WPF people ;) (-> don't get offended).

Answer (score 0):

You need to categorize those inputs into logical groups.

Imagine a form, similar to the Properties window in Visual Studio.
At the top is a combobox that lists all the major logical groups (Airplanes, Cars, Tractors, Buses, Etc). When selected, a datagridview appears with the first column being the name of the property, and second column holding the value.

All properties must have default values and must clearly reflect that in the datagridview.

A Save button in the lower right hand corner of the form is available that when pressed, saves the current logical group values.

The datagridview must be scrollable. You only show 15-20 items like the Properties window does.

When the user selects another logical group from the combobox, that logical groups properties and values are loaded.

This is a much cleaner way to get user input and is easily understood by the user.

Don't present the user with a 50x50 grid expecting them to know what to fill in and what not to. Pretend you are designing for a kid. Make it simple and easy to recognize and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, I am late to this party, but I have stumbled across this old question while browsing StackOverflow. I saw no WinForms solution among the answers, and I thought my answer could help people searching for a solution solely for this platform.

Below is the solution I implemented with our [iGrid WinForms grid](https://10tec.com/winforms-grid/) in a minute:

```cs
private iGDropDownList myCombo = new iGDropDownList();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myCombo.Items.Add(1);
    myCombo.Items.Add(2);
    myCombo.Items.Add(3);
    myCombo.Items.Add(4);

    iGrid1.DefaultCol.CellStyle.DropDownControl = myCombo;

    iGrid1.Cols.Count = 50;
    iGrid1.Rows.Count = 50;
}
```

And the corresponding screenshot:

[image: Cell combo box WinForms grid]

If you want, you can hide all combobox buttons by setting the ShowControlsInAllCells property to `false`.

One of the main benefits of using iGrid for such a solution is that it works extremely fast even on cheap low-end tablets. The cells of iGrid do not contain real combobox controls, this all is drawn in highly-optimized drawing code only in the cells currently visible in the viewport. Thus, for iGrid there is no difference whether you display 50 or 500'000 rows - the contents will be drawn and scrolled with the same speed.

You can add to this that iGrid is still being developed and supported, even in 2017!